# XML schemaLocation and targetNameSpace attributes

Tags: xml

I have some questions about schemaLocation and targetNameSpace attributes.

1. Why we use schemaLocation attributes? If two URLs that are specified as values of schemaLocation, what does it mean? Do they point to web resource?

2.
Does targetNameSpace appear in a schema? Does the value of it point to any web resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces are globally-unique identifiers (GUIDs) written in the form of a URI. They do not refer to resources on the web, except by accident (some people like to put something on the web to explain what the namespace is about). They are just unique strings. The main reason for writing them in the form of a URI is to tell you who owns and manages the namespace.

Schemas describe a vocabulary; if the vocabulary contains multiple namespaces, then each namespace is described in a different schema document. There is thus a relationship between schema documents (i.e. modules of a schema) and namespaces, which is indicated by the targetNamespace attribute of the xs:schema element.

Instance documents use a vocabulary, which may also contain multiple namespaces. The schemaLocation attribute describes a mapping from namespaces to the locations of schema documents that describe those namespaces. If there are two URIs, one will be a namespace, and the other the location of a schema document describing that namespace.